# vue-cli resolve xlink:href in svgs when referenced in <img src="">

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli, webpack-loader

In my vue-cli project, I need to reference an svg-file in an `<img>`-tag. That works.

Now inside this svg file, I have an `<image xlink:href="...">` – And this path is not touched or resolved by webpack.

Example:

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->
<img src="@/assets/someImage.svg" />

<!-- someImage.svg -->
<svg ...>
  <!-- none of these are working -->
  <image ... xlink:href="@/assets/arcade-bg-4.jpg"/>
  <image ... xlink:href="~@/assets/arcade-bg-4.jpg"/>
  <image ... xlink:href="./assets/arcade-bg-4.jpg"/>
  <image ... xlink:href="/src/assets/arcade-bg-4.jpg"/>
</svg>
```

The question now is, how I can tell webpack to solve paths inside this svg file?

Possible workarounds:
* put `arcade-bg-4.jpg` in `/public` and reference this in the `xlink:href`
* use inline-`<svg>` in `MyComponent.vue`

But I'd like to keep the `<img />`-tag and also keep the file-hashing feature from vue-cli.

Background:
I use this setup to achieve a (relatively) cross-browser-ready clip-mask with a `.jpg` instead of a `.png`, which is way smaller and more performant.

Comment: Were you able to find a work-around? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using just `href` instead of `xlink:href` in `<image>` of `<svg>`

or

You need to use require along with v-bind like so
`<image ... :href="require('@/assets/arcade-bg-4.jpg')" />`

or

In case of webpack you will need to add this to `vue-loader's` [options](https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/en/options.html) as either `transformToRequire` or [`transformAssetUrls`](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls) according to the version

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          transformToRequire: {
           image: ['xlink:href', 'href']
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but I don’t believe this will work unless you wrap your SVG as a vue component, which is undesirable.

Comment: If you want to use the file hashing feature from Vue CLI then the SVG then it needs to be within the Vuejs app scope.

Comment: I thought the hashing feature was a feature of webpack. I was hoping there would be a webpack setting to replace the `href` attributes of `<image>` and `<use>` tags in standalone SVG files.